# What is the term used for people who drive slowly?

Tags: etymology, terminology

I have heard terms like *bikers*, *racers* and *car racers* used for the people who drive quickly. But what are people called who drive slowly, or at normal speed, or very slowly (for old people who drive really slowly)?

*Drivers* cannot be use specifically for them as it denotes everybody.

So is there any particular term for these people?

Comment: The British TV programme 'Top Gear' has popularised the name 'Captain Slow'.

Comment: "Captain Slow" as in 'James May" yeah thats also good.

Comment: Snails - but depending on purpose, kerb crawlers?

Comment: The term I hear most in the UK is "slowbies". I wouldn't recommend "Captain Slow" unless you know the person you are talking to is familiar with Top Gear. (Believe it or not I'd never heard of that one until today).

Comment: Is there any particular english term so that we cannot relate these with the "snails" or "kerb crawlers". "Slowbies" again the term for everyone who is slow.

Comment: My favourite is 'drag-arse'.

Comment: And the user who edited the question left this explanation note, which is public, "Translated into English. Especially slowly" Charming!  I wasn't aware that the OP was written in a strange and foreign tongue. Talk about mutual respect . Americans and Brits too,  I suspect, use "fast" and "slow" as adverbs, so not really a non-native speaker error.

Comment: @peterG — And you are really suggesting the poster should use this expression? If you have an answer please follow SE recommendations and post it as such, so the poster can judge it by the score it attracts. Otherwise say nothing.

Comment: @Waseem — please follow SE guidelines and do not post answers in comments. This will allow your incorrect answer to be voted down. A "kerb crawler" is a term for a driver who drives slowly through a red-light district looking for prostitutes.

Comment: @David True - if I'd made this suggestion on ELL, I might have provided more context about its somewhat demotic nature. As regards making this an answer rather than a comment, I don't have citations or dictionary definitions to back it up, just my own experience of hearing others use the expression.

Comment: @David and before you can say "Jack Robinson", (a mere six hours later) destiny throws up this question on the active page: [Walk slow vs. Walk slowly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/350255/walk-slow-vs-walk-slowly)

Comment: @Mari-LouA — The explanation of my edit was cryptic, but I did leave a clear comment to the author explaining it. I find your comment equally cryptic. All I did was tried to improve the question so that people with limited education or for whom English is not the first language would read standard English, as they would expect from this site. The question wasn't about the trend in usage of adjectives as adverbs (and posts on the subject do not interest me) but about an expression to describe something. Encouraging people to continue to write poorly does them a disservice.

Comment: @David you did indeed leave a comment, but a rather condescending and patronising one. Besides you are also mistaken, *slow* and *fast* are also adverbs, telling someone that the phrase "drive slow" is not English, is wrong.  “Though *slowly* is the more common adverb and is certainly correct, *slow* is often just as good in adverbial sense. ….” [In fact, two idioms illustrate that point: *My watch runs slow*. *Take it slow*. Neither of those would sound right to us if we changed “slow” to “slowly.”*](http://grammarguide.copydesk.org/2008/06/14/adverbs-at-work-slow-and-slowly/) Bryan A. Garner

Comment: @Mari-LouA — The expression about Satan quoting from the bible comes to mind.

Comment: @David I thank you teaching me an idiom I did not know, I had to look that one up: [*The devil can quote Scripture for his own purpose*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/devil+can+cite+Scripture+for+his+own+purpose) I shall take it as a compliment, the devil is said to be sly and astute... By the way, the Bible is the title of a book, as such it should always be capitalised.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — Re capitalization of "Bible". Agreed. Noticed that after it was too late to edit. I make spelling mistakes too.

Answer (score 13):

"[Sunday driver](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sunday_driver)" is a term that might suit you.

Comment: I never heard of "sunday driver" I read about this and yeah it is the term for me right now, but I need some more terms for these. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Where I live (Netherlands) the term Sunday driver is used too, but it is primarily aimed at people who are inexperienced drivers (only drive to church on Sundays) and therefore drive either slow or erratically or a combination of both. Can also be used to indicate someone who doesn't anticipate (busy) traffic very well (because of a lack of experience under such road conditions).

Comment: @Tonny I also search the meaning of this and I found the same thing thats why ask about more precise term.

Comment: As we all know, [links can break or rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) over time, could you edit your answer, please?

Comment: You do give a citation in support, but for those old enough to remember the Beatles it is also familiar in the context of: [“She was a day tripper Sunday driver, yeah”](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beatles/daytripper.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Poky driver](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/poky) does the trick I believe.

> **2**. American English
>   doing things very slowly, especially in a way that is annoying:
>   *I got behind some poky driver on the freeway*.
>
> <sup>Longman Dictionary</sup>

Comment: The downvote (not mine) is for *not* giving the definition, and a link, which I did for you.

Comment: d'alar'cop's answer is *only* marginally better because it has a link, but as we know [links can break or rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) over time

Comment: @Mari-Lou A This is not a regular thing that I do. I just came across this post, and thought I could be of some help (I gave reference in my original post I think, without links or direct definitions that is). Downvotes don't bother me.

Answer (score -1):

In Singapore we called them road hogs, road hoggers and the act is described as road hogging.