# "Walk slow" vs. "walk slowly"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, flat-adverbs

I was wondering if *walk slow* and *walk slowly* are both correct or if there's a difference between them.

English isn't my first language and I'm sure the rules I learned would only accept *slowly* as the right word, because it follows a verb.

When I search for *walk slow* on Google I still get 250,000 results and for *walk slowly* I get 525,000 results, so *walk slow* can't be completely wrong.

Which one is right?

Comment: Oxford shows that *slow* can be used as an adverb all by itself. [See the example sentences](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slow).

Comment: The use of adjectives as adverbs seems to be common in AE, especially with *real*, as in *real good*. *Walk slow* (or better still, *walk real slow*) sounds like dialogue from a western.

Comment: @DavidHandelman While the OED notes that *real* meaning *very, extremely* is chiefly North American and Australian (or colloquial), the earlier sense of *really, genuinely* from which it derives dates to 1645 (chiefly Scottish, Irisn, and of the north of England), before there was much to distinguish North American English, or any Australian English at all.

Comment: Look up *flat adverb* (an adverb without *-ly*). For instance, see the links at [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129679/solid-used-as-an-adverb/129716#129716).

Comment: @David: In AmE *real good*, the word *real* is an intensifier meaning *very*. Anybody who thinks the British don't also use adjectives as intensifiers is just bloodily wrong.

Comment: I personally (Australian English, but leaning towards the British English side) wouldn't dream of saying "Walk slow". It sounds American. For me it's "Walk slowly" every time. (Not that American is bad, it's just not what I use)

Comment: "walk slow", "real good" etc are colloquial, aren't they?  Ie, acceptable and in use,  but not formally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are exceptions from certain rules. In this particular case, *slow* is almost similar to the word *fast*. 'Walk fast' is here the correct version. However, using *slow* it is 'walk slowly'. You could say 'walk slow' too, but *slowly* is more common. So we can see that these two words are definetely in marked contrast ;)

Comment: In the UK in the 50's and 60's I remember road signs with the words DEAD SLOW, warning motorists to slow down to a crawl,

Comment: "Walk fast" is correct simply because "fastly" isn't a word.

Comment: *Fastly* is a word. The OED lists most uses as obsolete and one usage (meaning "quickly, rapidly, speedily") as *rare*. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are right, as *slow* is also an adverb.

The differences between *slow* and *slowly* are listed as follows:

1. *Slow* emphasizes one's statement (lasting), while "slowly " indicates a way of one's action ( temporary ).
   E.g.  She walked slow. She walked slowly.
2. *Slowly* can be used in many situations  with flexible positions, either before a verb or after, and even put at the beginning of a setence. However, *slow* is used especially in the comparative and superlative forms, or in compounds. It generally follows some particular words such as "go, drive, run, speak, read, burn", or some intetjectional sentences led by "How".
3. Basically "slow" is more strong than "slowly" in tone.

Ref: OALD7-E&C. 
       Haici dictionary

Answer (score -1):

It would be difficult to say that one is right and the other wrong based on an internet search because the phrases "walk slow", "drive slow", "drive safe", etc. are common place, primarily in North America.

Noting the dictionary examples others have suggested or linked to, I would emphasise that most examples put the adverb "slow" in front of a verb, for example "slow-moving traffic".

Based on your search, support is given to my personal opinion of sticking with using "slowly" or "safely" after the verb, despite the common place use of "slow" or "safe".

Google Safely!

Answer (score -2):

*Slow* is an adjective.

Its use as an adverb is considered informal in standard English but seems to be standard in American English.

> Other adverbial use is informal and usually regarded as non-standard, as for example in he drives too slow and go as slow as you can. In such contexts standard English uses slowly instead.
>   — https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slow

Comment: You talk pretty tough but I think you have managed to miss something crucial here.

Comment: What is the crucial thing that I have managed to miss?

Comment: You got it backwards. The [-ly](http://www.finedictionary.com/-ly) suffix forms adjectives from nouns, or adverbs from adjectives. If you double check your source, you will see that slow is not a noun, so slowly can not be an adjective. If you want to argue for a distinction, you need to argue that slow is the adjective, and slowly is the adverb.

Comment: @sumelic - yes sorry that was a typo (now corrected). I was referring to the word 'slow' - as indicated by the Oxford Dictionaries link below. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: Why the additional downvotes? This is technically correct in British English. Slow as an adverb is informal in most contexts (as per the link above) but of course everyone understands it. It's equivalent to saying "You did good" instead of "You did well". 

It's curious that "fast" works the same both as an adjective and adverb. And I would say that it would make sense to formally allow slow to be used the same way as language evolves.

Answer (score -2):

Walk slow sounds like a command or a statement.
Walk slowly sounds more pleasing like a request.

If i were to command a group to slow down on a bridge i would tell them to walk slow.

If i were with friends, i would say, walk slowly.